# Liability in sexual assault

Tags: sexual-assault

I was told about a sexual assault. It was horrible, but it didn't involve actual intercourse or sexual contact beyond touching with clothes on. Either way, the victim is traumatized by what happened.

However, she's not my family member is afraid to tell her dad or anyone else that she was assaulted. I don't want to intervene in her life and go against her wishes by talking to her dad behind her back. I also want to give her the time to process what happened and hopefully gather the courage to do it herself.

With that said, I think her dad ***has to eventually*** know what happened and that a police report needs to be filed. So considering that I heard about a crime, can I be held liable if I never report it even if the victim never reports it herself or tells anyone else? Do I have to go to the police?

Comment: 1) You're contradicting yourself: did you *actually witness* the assault or were you merely told about it by the victim? 2) How old is the victim? 3) How old are you? 4) Jurisdiction?

Comment: I corrected myself. I heard about a crime. I'm an adult. The victim is 16. It's in the US.